# CPanel redirection addon domain

Tags: apache, dns, redirect, cpanel

I have a wildcard subdomain setup using CPanel, and I'd like to be able to add domain that will be linked to a subdomain without the usual redirection.

So when the user go to "test1.com", I'd like him to see exactly the same as test1.mysite.com, but I want the URL in the browser to remain test1.com, test1.com/page2.html, etc..

I don't want to use Iframe.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple if both **test1.com** and **test1.mysite.com** are on the **same cpanel account**.

1. Click on **Subdomains** link in **cPanel Home**.
2. In **Subdomain:** field, type **test1** and select **mysite.com**.
3. In the field **Document Root:**, type the path of the directory to which **test1.com** points.
4. Click **create**.
5. **test1.mysite.com** is now same as **test1.com**.

Hope that helps

Comment: Creating a subdomain of an addon domain, nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Login to cpanel and Subdomains, in Subdomain field type your subdomain name like "demo " and choose the domain name.

In cpanel server put the Document Root: "public_html/demo"it come automatically and Click create.

And upload your files in above path public_html/demo to access your subdomain live.